# Basis in the space of polynomials

Tags: vector-spaces

Do the vectors $\mathbf{p}_1(x)= 2+x+4x^2$, $\mathbf{p}_2(x)= 1-x+3x^2$ and 
$\mathbf{p}_3(x)= 3+2x+5x^2$ make a basis in the space of polynomials of degree at most $2$? If "yes", expand the polynomials $\mathbf{q}(x)= 7+8x+9x^2$ and $\mathbf{r}(x)=0$ in this basis.

I have no idea how to do this. Can somebody walk me through this?

Comment: Should p2 be $p_2(x)=1-x+3x^2$?

Comment: yes didn't know how to write it here

Comment: If you want to type in math mode, simply put a $ infront and $ after. Type p_1(x)=2+x+4x^2 with $ infront and afterwards and you will get the idea. Press edit and try

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vectors are linearly independent if and only if their coordinate vectors with respect to a basis are linearly independent. So you want to see whether the matrix
$$
B=\begin{bmatrix}
2 & 1 & 3\\
1 & -1 & 2\\
4 & 3 & 5
\end{bmatrix}
$$
has rank $3$, that is, it is invertible (I used the coordinate vectors with respect to the basis $\{1,x,x^2\}$).

If it is invertible, then the coordinates with respect to the “new” basis of the vector $\mathbf{q}(x)$ are
$$
B^{-1}\begin{bmatrix}7\\8\\9\end{bmatrix}
$$

Answer (score 1):

The vector space $\mathbb{P}_2$ is isomorphic to the vector space $\mathbb{R}_3$, because it is a vector space of degree 3 since it takes 3 vectors to form a basis for $\mathbb{P}_2$ (for example, $1$, $x$, and $x^2$).

But this is just a formal way of stating the concept that the set of all polynomials of degree of at most 2 is very similar to the set of all 3-tuples $(a,b,c)$. Given three linearly independent vectors in either set, we can generate any other vector via a linear combination of them.

And this helps us because we're very familiar with working with vectors in $\mathbb{R}_3$. Now, how do we solve the problem using this information? Well, this is a set of three vectors in a space of degree 3. If we can show that they're linearly independent, then they must be a basis set. There are ways to figure out if a set of polynomials are linearly independent, but let's take an easier route by taking advantage of the isomorphism between this vector space and  $\mathbb{R}_3$ by somehow converting these vectors into vectors in $\mathbb{R}_3$. The easiest way to do that is to represent $\mathbf{p}_1, \mathbf{p}_2$, and $\mathbf{p}_3$ using the standard basis $B=\{1,x,x^2\}$. The representations are:
$[\mathbf{p}_1]_B=\left[ \begin{array}{c}
2 \\
1 \\
4
\end{array} \right]$, $[\mathbf{p}_1]_B=\left[ \begin{array}{c}
1 \\
-1 \\
3
\end{array} \right]$, $[\mathbf{p}_1]_B=\left[ \begin{array}{c}
3 \\
2  \\
5 
\end{array} \right]$

Now, because the two vector spaces are isomorphic, **if these representations of your three vectors form a basis set for $\mathbb{R}_3$ then your three vectors will form a basis set for $\mathbb{P}_2$**. That is the key concept here that allows us to make our lives much easier, because we have *tons* of ways of working with vectors in $\mathbb{R}_3$! For example, let's plop these guys into a matrix and check if it can be row reduced to the identity matrix. When we do that, we find that it does, and so we're done. They do indeed form a basis for $\mathbb{P}_2$.